# Соответствие полей в базе данных Yii2/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Такая задача:

1. Следует загрузить 1 CSV файл с полями в базу данных:
   `id`, `name`, `sku`, `price`
2. Загрузить 2 CSV файл в другую таблицу в базу данных:
   `name`, `price` (тут по сути нет уникального поля кроме `name`)
3. Сделать соотношение данных одной таблице к другой по какому-нибудь полю рода **id=id**
4. Вывести эти данные в одну форму и выгрузить тем же CSV
   Примерно: `id`, `name`, `sku`, `price`

Как реализовать соответствие полей в на PHP?

Использую для этого фреймворк *Yii2*.

Comment: Не очень понятно следующее: у вас должно быть 2 таблицы, в одной таблице полные данные, а в другой таблице те же самые данные, но без id и sku? Какой в этом смысл?

Answer (score 1):

**Не очень понятно следующее:** у вас должно быть 2 таблицы, в одной таблице полные данные, а в другой таблице те же самые данные, но без id и sku? Какой в этом смысл?

Если вопрос заключается только в

> Как реализовать соответствие полей в на PHP?
>
> Использую для этого фреймворк Yii2.

То ответ следующий:

У вас должно быть 2 сущности (=таблицы) они объявляются классами с привязкой к ActiveRecord.

В этих классах вы должны будете прописать соответствующие методы (называться они могут иначе, как и возвращаемые значения, так как связываться 1 таблица к другой может как hasOne, так и hasMany)

```
class Table1 extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getTable2()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Table2::className(), ['name' => 'name']); // первый name это поле в Table1, 2ой name - поле в Table2
    }

    ...
}

class Table2 extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getTable1()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Table1::className(), ['name' => 'name']); // первый name это поле в Table2, 2ой name - поле в Table1
    }

    ...
}
```

Более подробно Вы можете ознакомиться с ActiveRecords в Yii2 здесь https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/db-active-record/ или на первоисточнике (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html)

Comment: Да, просто у меня есть 1 CSV с id/name/sku это с сайта и 2 CSV это с каталога, мне нужно синхронизировать эти данные чтобы контролировать и каталог и сайт, но так как в CSV каталога кроме поля 'name' нет больше уникальных полей, я думал чтобы заливался CSV из каталога в базу, и связь происходила по принципу "соотношения" по id. Т.е. Сделать гинерацию id для CSV каталога при занесении в базу (2 таблица) и их соотнести с данными по id из 1-ой таблицы. ID = ID и вывести в Grid View для удобства просмотра после и экспортировать потом обратно в единую таблицу

Comment: Разница в этих 2-ух CSV только в поле Price будет, и мне нужно этот момент синхронизировать чтобы была одна цена на эти 2 CSV, что-то типа "обработка прайсов"